# Creating a Rails change log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am pretty new to rails (and development) and have a requirement to create a change log. Let's say you have an employees table. On that table you have an employee reference number, a first name, and a last name. When either the first name or last name changes, I need to log it to a table somewhere for later reporting. I only need to log the change, so if employee ref 1 changes from Bill to Bob, then I need to put the reference number and first name into a table. The change table can have all the columns that mnight change, but most only be populated with the reference number and the changed field. I don't need the previous value either, just the new one. hope that makes sense.

Looked at gems such as paper trail, but they seem very complicated for what I need. I don't ever need to manipulate the model or move versions etc, I just need to track which fields have changed, when, and by whom.

I'd appreciate your recommendations.

Comment: I'd say stick with paper_trail or vestal_versions.  You may not need all the functionality, but they'll do the job and don't have much overhead.  Of the 2, paper_trail appears to be more active.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on building your own changelog, based on your requirements you can do so using a few callbacks.  First create your log table:

```
def up
  create_table :employee_change_logs do |t|
    t.references :employee
    # as per your spec - copy all column definitions from your employees table
  end
end
```

In your `Employee` model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employee_change_logs

  before_update :capture_changed_columns
  after_update :log_changed_columns

  # capture the changes before the update occurs
  def capture_changed_columns
    @changed_columns = changed
  end

  def log_changed_columns
    return if @changed_columns.empty?
    log_entry = employee_change_logs.build
    @changed_columns.each{|c| log_entry.send(:"#{c}=", self.send(c))}
    log_entry.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: One issue with this. the log table has a field for the current_user who made the change. However, I cannot pass this  into the model and understand this is the wrong this to do anyway. Should I move everything to the controller, and if so don't I lose the ability to capture the changes before the update?

Comment: @GarethBurrows: The simplest solution would be to ensure that the current_user is accessible at the model level.  This does break separation of concerns somewhat and is usually frowned upon, but it works if you absolutely need it. Alternatively, you can set the modifying user in the controller as a virtual attribute (not database-backed) on the Employee instance.  Then add some validation before_update to ensure this attribute is being set, and pass it along when creating your log_entry.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the gem [vestal_versions](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions).

To version an `ActiveRecord` model, simply add versioned to your class like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  versioned

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name

  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

And use like this:

```
@user.update_attributes(:last_name => "Jobs", :updated_by => "Tyler")
@user.version # => 2
@user.versions.last.user # => "Tyler"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we did was put an around filter in the application controller. This was how I get the current_employee into the employee model, which was the challenge, especially for a newbie like me!

```
around_filter :set_employee_for_log, :if => Proc.new { @current_account && 
@current_account.log_employee_changes? && @current_employee }

def set_employee_for_log
  Thread.current[:current_employee] = @current_employee.id
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      Thread.current[:current_employee ] = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Next, in the employee model I defined which fields I was interested in monitoring

```
CHECK_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name']
```

then I added some hooks to actually capture the changes IF logging is enabled at the account level

```
before_update :capture_changed_columns
after_update :log_changed_columns, :if => Proc.new { self.account.log_employee_changes? }

def capture_changed_columns
  @changed_columns = changed
  @changes = changes
end

def log_changed_columns
  e = EmployeeChangeLog.new
  Employee::CHECK_FIELDS.each do |field|
  if self.send("#{field}_changed?")
    e.send("#{field}=", self.send(field))
  end
end

if e.changed?
  e.update_attribute(:account_id, self.account.id)
  e.update_attribute(:employee_id, self.id)
  e.update_attribute(:employee_ref, self.employee_ref)
  e.update_attribute(:user_id, Thread.current[:current_employee])
  e.save
else return
end
```

end

And that;s it. If the account enables it, the app keeps an eye on specific fields and then all changes to those fields are logged to a table, creating an simple audit trail.